# Can you use "非常非常‘ to emphasize how much you think of something?

Tags: grammar, usage, adverbs

I'm trying to figure out if a common English usage such as the one below is used in Chinese.

> I really *really* `<verb>` something

Could I say something like this?

> 我非常非常喜欢这首歌

Could I use this in spoken Chinese? Could it be written this way if it is a more informal context: e.g. a diary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. You can even repeat it more times (`非常非常非常`) if you want...

Like the English usage ("really, really") it isn't something you'd put in formal writings, but its certainly common enough in dialogue or advertisement or blogs/internet posts, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say "非常非常" to emphasize how much you think of something.

It is an informal usage, so of course it is ok to be in an informal context like in a diary, not in a formal paper.